# Multiple Roles for a single User

Tags: grails, spring-security, roles

The Following Code Adds Multiple Roles to a Single user, it also should be noted that this will only work for a single session as we're trying to define the roles and users every time we start the app, to prevent any crashes due to that add a check for the database and create the roles and user IF they don't exist.

```
import trippinspring.*

class BootStrap {

def init = { servletContext ->

  def adminRole = new SpringRole(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
  def userRole = new SpringRole(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)

  def testUser = new SpringUser(username: 'me', enabled: true, password: 'password')
  testUser.save(flush: true)

if (!testUser.authorities.contains(adminRole)) {
new SpringUserSpringRole(springUser: testUser, springRole: adminRole).save(flush: true,failOnError: true)
}

if (!testUser.authorities.contains(userRole)) {
new SpringUserSpringRole(springUser: testUser, springRole: userRole).save(flush: true,failOnError: true)
}
}
}
```

Most of the code is a direct reference to Aram Arabyan's answer, and Ian Roberts comments with some fixes to work with my code.

Comment: Is the `def userRole = new SpringUser(...)` a typo - it should be `new SpringRole`?

Comment: Yes sorry it was a typo, but the code still doesn't compile after with the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if (!testUser.authorities.contains(adminRole)) {
    new SpringUserSpringRole(user: testUser, role: adminRole).save(flush: true,failOnError: true)
  }

 if (!testUser.authorities.contains(userRole)) {
    new SpringUserSpringRole(user: testUser, role: userRole).save(flush: true,failOnError: true)
  }
```

Comment: Error executing bootstraps: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Comment: please change save(flush: flush) to save(flush: true,failOnError: true)

Comment: I still seem to get the same error sir, could it be that there's something wrong with my code rather than yours? I'll update my code above for you to see.

Comment: okay, so I cleared my user database just in case there was an error with that, N~ow I'm getting a different error: ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'myspringclassspring.SpringUserSpringRole' on field 'springRole': rejected value [null];

Comment: `SpringRole.save` (when used without `failOnError:true`) will return `null` if the object fails validation, and when you then try and use that `null` to create a `SpringUserSpringRole` you'll get that validation error.  If you add the `failOnError`, clean out your database and try again you should see the real underlying problem.

Comment: look like your 'adminRole' and 'userRole' are null
can you show code of SpringUserSpringRole

Comment: Cleaned Database and switched your "user" and "role" assignments to "SpringRole" and "SpringUser"

Comment: Fixed my project and added you as a reference Ty guys

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, maybe you should try creating a hierarchy for your roles instead of adding two roles for a single user: 
[see doc](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/14%20Hierarchical%20Roles.html).